# Simplify checking what type it is and format the string with reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Is there a way for me to simplify the if(value is X) then customize the ToString()?

```
var value = FindBodyLine(iwant, props, obj);

if (value != null)
{
  if(value is DateTime)
   {    
    var date = value as DateTime? ?? new DateTime();
    sb.Append(date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")));
   }
   else if(value is float)
   {    
     var floatData = value as float?? new float();
     sb.Append(floatData.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE")));
   }
}



 private object FindBodyLine(string iwant, PropertyInfo[] props, object obj)
 {

   var itemFound = from x in props where x.Name == iwant select x;

   var value = itemFound.First().GetValue(obj, null);  
   return value;
 }
```

I thought about having a Dictionary

```
 typeOf(DateTime), "mm/DD/yyyy"
 typeOf(float), "de-De"
```

and have a looup but I can't convert value to the type.

Comment: Is your question actually about "I can't convert value to the type."? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Why not value.GetType() ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [double dispatch / visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and take advantage of `dynamic` type:

```
public class ValueFormatter
{
    public string Format(object value)
    {           
        return Format(value as dynamic);
    }

    private string Format(DateTime date)
    {
        return date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }

    private string Format(float floatData)
    {
        return floatData.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"));
    }

    // ...
}
```

You could now rewrite your code:

```
var formatter = new ValueFormatter();
var value = FindBodyLine(iwant, props, obj);
sb.Append(formatter.Format(value));
```